# Minimum degree of a Random Graph

Tags: probability-distributions, random-graphs

How do I find the limit distribution of the minimum degree of $G(n,p)$. Given that:
$$p = \frac{\ln n + \ln \ln n + \ln \ln \ln n}{n}$$
Any hint or solution is very much appreciated. Thanks in Advance